# Iterate and sum values based on a condition in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have 10k rows of customers per employee name and sent emails, this is a basic sample of the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['Sara', 'CustomerA', 4], ['John', 'CustomerA', 0], ['Silvia', 'CustomerA', 0],['Sara', 'CustomerB', 0],['John', 'CustomerB', 1],['Silvia', 'CustomerB', 1]]),

                   columns=['Employee', 'Customer', 'Opened Emails'])
```

df

```
    Employee    Customer    Opened Emails
0   Sara          CustomerA     4
1   John          CustomerA     0
2   Silvia        CustomerA     0
3   Sara          CustomerB     0
4   John          CustomerB     1
5   Silvia        CustomerB     1
```

Now I want to make a report for each customer to see if they already opened emails from different employees and notify employees with 0 Opened emails.

What I did so far is:

1- Grouping the dataframe by customer and employee and used `describe()` with `top`:

```
total = df.groupby(['Customer','Employee'])['Sent Emails'].describe()[['top']]

                       top
Customer    Employee    
CustomerA   John        0
            Sara        4
            Silvia      0
CustomerB   John        1
            Sara        0
            Silvia      1
```

2-

```
total.astype({"top": int})
```

3- I want to Iterate over each customer and see if the `sum()` of top > 0, then notify other employees with 0 that this customer is receiving emails.

The issue that I cannot find the best way to access values and do the condition, this is what I tried but it seems not a good way with lots of errors

```
for index, column in df.iterrows():
    if column['top'].sum() != 0:
        if column['top'] == 0:
        print(column['Employee'])
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you share your expected output ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can calculate opened emails by customer `cs`, and opened emails by customer sent from each employee `ecs`, and then find records where `cs` is greater than 0 (customer opened at least some emails), but `ecs` is equal to 0 (customer opened no emails from a specific employee):

```
# convert opened emails to integer
df['Opened Emails'] = df['Opened Emails'].astype(int)

# opened emails by customer
cs = df.groupby('Customer')['Opened Emails'].transform('sum')

# opened emails by customer and employee
ecs = df.groupby(['Customer', 'Employee'])['Opened Emails'].transform('sum')

# employee-customer pairs with 0 opened emails
# while overall customer opened emails is greater than 0
df.loc[(cs.gt(0)) & (ecs.eq(0))]
```

Output:

```
  Employee   Customer  Opened Emails
1     John  CustomerA              0
2   Silvia  CustomerA              0
3     Sara  CustomerB              0
```

So, John and Silvia can be notified that CustomerA is receiving emails, and Sara can be notified that CustomerB is receiving emails.

Answer (score 0):

```py
print(df[df["Customer"] == "CustomerA"]["Opened Emails"].astype(int).sum())
print(df[df["Customer"] == "CustomerB"]["Opened Emails"].astype(int).sum())
```

Output

```
4
2
```

Not a very optimal solution but it worked ;)